# What is a Plain English term for "Device" in the USA?

Tags: terminology

I'm working on a web application. It runs in Chrome and Safari, so that supports just about any modern device.

I'm worried that "device" might be a confusing term for the average person. Here are a few ideas I've come up with so far:

- Web Device
- Internet Device
- Internet Computer

Does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: I feel this should be flagged as a Language question. How does it relate to UX?

Comment: Device is fine. FYI, however, note that mobile Safari and Safari are not exactly the same browser. And lots of android phones are still running browsers that aren't using the same rendering engine as Chrome.

Comment: @Pdxd - [This is currently being discussed](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1581/when-did-copy-stop-being-part-of-ux?cb=1).

Comment: @pdxd it feels like a UX question to me. The OP is specifically concerned about how his choice of words is going to affect the _usability_ of his web-app. Accessibility of copy is a valid usability concern for websites.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic for ux.stackexchange.com and should be migrated to http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @greenforest I strenuously disagree. Creating copy that matches the users mental model is a fundamental part of UX. Nothing in [the faq](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) prohibits questions about copy, and this question is about a specific case that many UX profesionals will encounter at some point in their lives. A good UX answer is of clear benefit to the community.

Comment: @Racheet Agree with the comment about copy and UX. However, it's a fine balance. While the question might not be strictly off topic for UX I think a migration to  http://english.stackexchange.com/about will lead to even more great answers.

Comment: @greenforest You may be right, the question would certainly get useful answers at the english SE, I was mostly objecting to the statement that it wasn't _also on topic here_, which is the reason given for closing. I'm sorry if I came across more stridently than I had intended to.

Comment: Can you just say "runs on Chrome and Safari"? Your example is like saying "the steering wheel in your *car*", well where else is there a steering wheel? Drop the needless words and say what is actually supported.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be completely clear to all possible users, you probably want to steer away from a nonspecific word like "device".

I'd suggest using the compound phrase **"your phone or tablet"** instead.

Whilst it's technically true that your app will work on devices that aren't phones or tablets, the people who own those devices and use them to browse the net already know that, so you don't need to tell them.

The only people who might be confused are people using either a phone or a tablet, and that's what they'll call the their device, so that's the word you need to use.

Comment: Just a note, I'm a speaker of British English, so I'll defer to an American speaker if it somehow turns out that those words aren't common usage across the pond.

Comment: Racheet, but more than half our website vistiors are using Windows/Mac (non mobile/non tablet). wouldn't they think "oh well, I guess this is one of those "app things" I can't use on my PC?

Comment: ahh right, I didn't realise it wasn't a mobile specific web-app. In that case, I'd be doubly careful of using the word "device", it doesn't normally refer to computers in everyday speech, it normally means "appliances". How do you feel about "your phone, tablet or computer"?

Comment: too long :)  Internet Device would be better. Or Web device

Answer (score 1):

**Device** is pretty standard.  Other than that, you could check out its [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/device):

[image]

Comment: I think device is the common term in web-design circles, but I wouldn't expect my grandfather to know which kind of "device" some random website was talking about. Especially if he'd forgotten that he could use his telephone to access web-pages.

Comment: I think it all depends on audience and how the copy is actually being used.  The OP really needs to narrow the question down to exactly how the copy is going to be used to get a quality answer.  Right now it's too broad.